# Declaring uninterpreted polyadic functions with Z3Py

Tags: python-3.x, z3, z3py

Using Z3Py, I'm trying to write a function `decl_func(fname, arity)` which takes in two arguments : `fname`, the name of the function to be declared, and `arity`, its number of arguments, and returns the corresponding (uninterpreted) Z3 function over integers. The problem is that the value of `arity` cannot be predetermined, so the function body cannot be

```
return Function(fname, IntSort(), IntSort())
```

or

```
return Function(fname, IntSort(), IntSort(), IntSort())
```

as it would be for unary or binary functions. Here's one crude workaround I've considered :

```
exec('f = Function(\'%s\', %s)' % (fname, ('IntSort(), ' * arity + 'IntSort()')))
return f
```

but this does not work, seemingly due to the way `exec` handles variable declarations (I'm using Python 3, if that is relevant).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is about [variadic functions in Python](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Python).

> You can use the same "*" syntax to apply the function to an existing list of arguments:

Therefore, something like this *should* work:

```
sorts = [IntSort(), IntSort(), IntSort()]
return Function(fname, *sorts)
```